# Can SQL Server SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS be safely converted to Latin1_General_CI_AS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

We have a legacy database with some (older) columns using "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and more recent changes have used "Latin1_General_CI_AS".

This is a pain as joins need the additional COLLATE statement to work.

I'd like to bring everything up to "Latin1_General_CI_AS". From what I can gather they are more or less identical collations and I won't lose data during this process...

Does anyone know if this is the case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is more info on this MSDN forum:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/196b4586-1338-434d-ba8c-49fa3c9bdeeb/

Which states:

> You should see little difference if the collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS or Latin1_General_CI_AS, but both have instances where they are faster or slower than the other.
>
> Latin1_General_CI_AS :- Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-
>   sensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive
>
> SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS:- Latin1-General, case-insensitive,
>   accent-sensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive for Unicode
>   Data, SQL Server Sort Order 52 on Code Page 1252 for non-Unicode Data

Therefore in my opinion you shouldn't see a difference, especially if your data is only a-z0-9

Comment: _"you should see little difference"_ except when you want to join or compare results from INFORMATION_SCHEMA with a temp table and AzureSQL says it cant.

Answer (score 48):

Here is a more complete answer:

https://www.olcot.co.uk/revised-difference-between-collation-sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as-and-latin1_general_ci_as/

The key difference between these collations is in how they apply character expansion rules.  Certain Latin characters may be expanded into multiple characters.  The SQL_xxxx collations may ignore these character expansions when working with non-unicode text, but apply them for unicode text.  As a result: joins, sorts, and comparisons may return different results when using one collation versus the other.

Example:

Under `Latin1_General_CI_AS` these two statements return the same set of records, as `ß` is expanded to `ss`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable3 WHERE Comments = 'strasse'
SELECT * FROM MyTable3 WHERE Comments = 'straße'
```

When using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` the above statements return different records, since the `ß` is treated as a different character than `ss`.

Comment: +1 for finding and mentioning character expansions. I included that (and a link to the Unicode documentation mentioning it) in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34342009/577765) and added several more items to be aware of :-).

Comment: What if ``Comments`` is ``NVARCHAR``? ``SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`` doesn't support Unicode and thus falls back to ``Latin1_General_CI_AS``, which handles 'ass' = 'aß'. How can ``NVARCHAR`` be forced to compare 'ss' <> 'ß'?

Comment: @Hannobo You can specify a collation when defining any text field in a table, temp table, or table variable. For many text based operations, you can also specify a collation by adding ` COLLATE {desired_collation}`. I'm not sure, but you might be able to specify a collation when defining a variable. Since I'm answering this off the top of my head, I recommend you review the SQL Server T-SQL documentation for syntax and further details.

Comment: @Zarepheth I did, but the documentation as well as tests show that any collation (either on field or in query) falls back to standard Unicode for NVARCHAR. Only way I found is casting to VARCHAR dynamically.

Comment: @Hannobo (and Zarepheth): Don't convert to `VARCHAR` as that can result in data-loss. You need to use either a Hungarian or binary collation as those are the only ones that do not equate those particular characters. So try `COLLATE Hungarian_Technical_100_CI_AS_SC` or `COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2`. For more details, please see my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42883638/577765) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27113270/577765). Also, variables (and string literals) always have the collation of the current database's default collation and cannot be given a different one.

Answer (score 34):

If you are going to change the Collation of a Database, then there is definitely stuff you should know about so that you can plan accordingly:

- Regarding data-loss potential:

  - `NVARCHAR` fields are all Unicode, which is a single character set, so there can't be any data loss for these fields (this also covers XML fields which are also stored as UTF-16 Little Endian). Meta-data fields that store the object / column / index / etc names are all `NVARCHAR` so no need to worry about those.
  - `VARCHAR` fields having different Collations but the same Code Page between the differing Collations will not be a problem since the Code Page is the character set.
  - `VARCHAR` fields having different Collations and moving to a different Code Page (when changing Collations) *can* have data loss if any of the characters being used are not represented in the new Code Page. HOWEVER, this is only an issue when physically changing the Collation of a particular field (described below) and would not happen upon changing the default Collation of a database.
- Local variables and string literals get their Collation from the Database default. Changing the database default will change the Collation used for both local variables and string literals. But changing the Database's default Collation does not change the Collation used for existing string columns in the tables in that Database. This generally should not cause any problems when comparing or concatenating a column with a literal and/or variable since the literals and variables will take on the Collation of the column due to Collation Precedence. The only potential problem would be Code Page conversions that might occur for characters of values between 128 - 255 that are not available in the Code Page used by the Collation of the column.
- If you are expecting a predicate / comparison / sort / concatenation / etc for a column to behave differently upon changing the Database's default Collation, then you will need to explicitly change that column's Collation using the following command:

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE [{table_name}]
     ALTER COLUMN [{column_name}]
     {same_datatype}
     {same_NULL_or_NOT NULL_setting}
     COLLATE {name_of_Database_default_Collation};
  ```

  Be sure to specify the *exact same* datatype and `NULL` / `NOT NULL` setting that are currently being used, else they can revert to the default if not already being the default value. After that, if there are any indexes on any of the string columns that just had their Collation changed, then you need to rebuild those indexes.
- Changing the Database's default Collation will change the Collation of certain database-specific meta-data, such as the `name` field in both `sys.objects`, `sys.columns`, `sys.indexes`, etc. Filtering these system Views against local variables or string literals won't be a problem since the Collation will be changing on both sides. But, if you JOIN any of the local system Views to temporary tables on string fields, and the Database-level Collation between the local database and `tempdb` doesn't match, then you will get the "Collation mismatch" error. This is discussed below along with the remedy.
- One difference between these two Collations is in how they sort certain characters for `VARCHAR` data (this does not affect `NVARCHAR` data). The non-EBCDIC `SQL_` Collations use what is called "String Sort" for `VARCHAR` data, while all other Collations, and even `NVARCHAR` data for the non-EBCDIC `SQL_` Collations, use what is called "Word Sort". The difference is that in "Word Sort", the dash `-` and apostrophe `'` (and maybe a few other characters?) are given a very low weight and are essentially ignored unless there are no other differences in the strings. To see this behavior in action, run the following:

  ```sql
  DECLARE @Test TABLE (Col1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('aa');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('ac');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('ah');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('am');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('aka');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('akc');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('ar');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('a-f');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('a_e');
  INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('a''kb');

  SELECT * FROM @Test ORDER BY [Col1] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
  -- "String Sort" puts all punctuation ahead of letters

  SELECT * FROM @Test ORDER BY [Col1] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS;
  -- "Word Sort" mostly ignores dash and apostrophe
  ```

  Returns:

  ```
  String Sort
  -----------
  a'kb
  a-f
  a_e
  aa
  ac
  ah
  aka
  akc
  am
  ar
  ```

  and:

  ```
  Word Sort
  ---------
  a_e
  aa
  ac
  a-f
  ah
  aka
  a'kb
  akc
  am
  ar
  ```

  While you will "lose" the "String Sort" behavior, I'm not sure that I would call that a "feature". It is a behavior that has been deemed undesirable (as evidenced by the fact that it wasn't brought forward into any of the Windows collations). However, it *is* a definite difference of behavior between the two collations (again, just for non-EBCDIC `VARCHAR` data), and you might have code and/or customer expectations based upon the "String Sort" behavior. **This requires testing your code and possibly researching to see if this change in behavior might have any negative impact on users.**
- Another difference between `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS` is the ability to do [Expansions](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Expansions) on `VARCHAR` data (`NVARCHAR` data can already do these for most `SQL_` Collations), such as handling `æ` as if it were `ae`:

  ```sql
  IF ('æ' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS =
      'ae' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS';
  END;

  IF ('æ' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS =
      'ae' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS)
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS';
  END;
  ```

  Returns:

  ```
  Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
  ```

  The only thing you are "losing" here is *not* being able to do these expansions. Generally speaking, this is another benefit of moving to a Windows Collation. However, just like with the "String Sort" to "Word Sort" move, the same caution applies: it is a definite difference of behavior between the two collations (again, just for `VARCHAR` data), and you might have code and/or customer expectations based upon *not* having these mappings. **This requires testing your code and possibly researching to see if this change in behavior might have any negative impact on users.**

  <sup>(first noted in @Zarepheth's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22055580/577765) and expanded on here)</sup>
- Another difference (that is also a benefit of moving to a Windows Collation) is that filtering a `VARCHAR` column that is indexed on `NVARCHAR` literal / variable / column you will no longer invalidate the index on the `VARCHAR` column. This is due to the Windows Collations using the same Unicode sorting and comparison rules for both `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` data. Because the sort order is the same between the two types, when the `VARCHAR` data gets converted into `NVARCHAR` (explicitly or implicitly due to datatype precedence), the order of items in the index is still valid. For more details on this behavior, please see my post: [Impact on Indexes When Mixing VARCHAR and NVARCHAR Types](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/07/10/impact-on-indexes-when-mixing-varchar-and-nvarchar-types/).
- The server-level Collation is used to set the Collation of the system databases, which includes `[model]`. The `[model]` database is used as a template to create new databases, which includes `[tempdb]` upon each server startup. So, if the Database's default collation does not match the instance's default Collation *and* you join local tables to temporary tables on string fields, then you will get the Collation-mismatch error. Fortunately there is a somewhat easy way to correct for collation differences between the database that is "current" when `CREATE #TempTable` is executed and `[tempdb]`. When creating temporary tables, declare a collation (on string columns) using the `COLLATE` clause and use either a specific collation (if you know that the DB will always be using that collation), or `DATABASE_DEFAULT` (if you don't always know the collation of the DB where this code will execute):

  ```sql
  CREATE TABLE #Temp (Col1 NVARCHAR(40) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT);
  ```

  This is not necessary for table variables since they get their default Collation from the "current" database. However, if you have both table variables and temporary tables and join them on string fields, then you will need to use `COLLATE {specific_collation}` or `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` as shown directly above.
- The server-level collation also controls local variable names, `CURSOR` variable names, and `GOTO` labels. While none of these would be impacted by the specific change being dealt with in this Question, it is at least something to be aware of.
- It is best to use the most recent version of the desired collation, if multiple versions are available. Starting in SQL Server 2005, a "90" series of collations was introduced, and SQL Server 2008 introduced a "100" series of collations. You can find these collations by using the following queries:

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() WHERE [name] LIKE N'%[_]90[_]%'; -- 476

  SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() WHERE [name] LIKE N'%[_]100[_]%'; -- 2686
  ```
- ALSO, while the question asks about case-insensitive Collations, it should be noted that if someone else is looking to make a similar change but is using case-sensitive Collations, then another difference between SQL Server Collations and Windows Collations, *for `VARCHAR` data only*, is which case sorts first. Meaning, if you have both `A` and `a`, the `SQL_` Collations will sort `A` before `a`, while the non-`SQL_` Collations (and the `SQL_` Collations when dealing with `NVARCHAR` data) will sort `a` before `A`.

For a lot more info and details on changing the Collation of a Database or of the entire Instance, please see my post:
[Changing the Collation of the Instance, the Databases, and All Columns in All User Databases: What Could Possibly Go Wrong?](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/06/11/changing-the-collation-of-the-instance-and-all-columns-across-all-user-databases-what-could-possibly-go-wrong/)

For more info on working with strings and collations, please visit: [Collations Info](https://collations.info/)

Comment: @Jay Thanks! Please re-read as I just made some adjustments. Some of the info re: literals / variables and indexes was not entirely correct. Now it is. And I added two links to posts of mine that did not exist when I submitted this answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM ::fn_helpcollations()
WHERE name IN (
'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS',
'Latin1_General_CI_AS'
)
```

...gives...

Latin1_General_CI_AS:
Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive

SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS:
Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive **for Unicode Data, SQL Server Sort Order 52 on Code Page 1252 for non-Unicode Data**

So from this, I would infer that the code page used is the same (Latin1-General => 1252), so you *should* encounter no loss of data - if anything were to change post-conversion it might be the sort order - which is probably immaterial.

Answer (score -1):

To do that go to properties of your data base and select options.

Then change the collection type to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS.

[image]